# How to select next array keys

Tags: php, loops, iteration

```
$result =   
  Array
  (
   [kpi] => calls
   [team] => team1
   [content] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => June
                [last_name] => Fernandez
                [user_name] => junef
                [result] => 19
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Juan
                [last_name] => Fernandez
                [user_name] => juanf
                [result] => 19
            )
    )

  Array
  (
   [kpi] => emails
   [team] => team2
   [content] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => May
                [last_name] => Fernandez
                [user_name] => mayf
                [result] => 19
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => July
                [last_name] => Fernandez
                [user_name] => july
                [result] => 19
            )
    )
```

//////

```
foreach($result as $teams){
  print_r(next($teams));
}
```

Returns nothing
In each loop i want to select the next keys and values of the array.

Comment: Not teams but next of results  variable `print_r(next($result));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the index

```
foreach ($result as $i => $teams) {
  if ($i+1 < count($result)) {
    print_r($result[$i+1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'car';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
?>
```